# Popup user alertmessage

Tags: java, libgdx

Is there a way to popup a message to the user during the buildStage()?

Specifically my game loads information from a file. If the read fails, I want to be able to inform the user about it, BEFORE I reach the render() method.

```
/-------------\
| Saved Game  |
| - - - - - - |
| Cannot load |
|             |
| New Game!   |
|             |
|   [Ok]      |
\-------------/
```

so

```
try
{
   gamePlay = loadGame();
}
catch(IOException e)
{
   showBooBooMessage();
   gamePlay = newGame();
}
```

Comment: you cannot "inform" a user before a render method. because whatever you are trying to inform with is not rendered to screen. Sound could be the exception but libgdx sound is supposed to be started from the ui thread too (because of resource management I think)
Perhaps you need to ask a different question? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: The user is expecting to play (continue) a saved game. If I cannot load the saved game, then I must create a new one. The obvious place to inform the user is at the point where the load error occurs. I could of course cache the message, then pop it up in the render() but that seemed to be needlessly complicated. Oh well, if I cannot, then I will cache it. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: when using libgdx, chances are that the "loadGame()" function runs on the ui thread anyway. I would just create the popup where you are doing as an actor now, give it an action to fade in (or just set visible) and add it to the current stage. then remove it again when the user has clicked

Comment: I was under the impression that actors are only "drawn" during the render(). I tried creating a popup in the Exception block, but it was never displayed. When I move the popup into the render() then it was shown. So it seems that only during the render() loop are screen draws processed. So I am saving the message in a field, then showing it during the next render() pass. Thanks

Comment: You are sort of correct, in the render function (which also runs on the ui thread) is where the draw functions are usually called. However. This does not mean you cannot create actors + add to stage anywhere else on the ui thread. And since usually all of libgdx runs on the ui thread you should be able to create your actors anywhere which then automatically get rendered when render is called (keep in mind some async tasks return on other threads, but here you can use gdx.app.postrunnable() to hop code back on the ui thread). Check this out: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/The-life-cycle